# Use Babel Generated AMD Modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, babeljs

I have an existing app that is all AMD modules based and use require.js on bundling up things. I need to bring a bunch of es2015 react code into this app as AMD modules and use Babel to turn them into AMD modules. Here is my babel config

```
 babel:
  options:
    sourceMap: false
    plugins: [ 'transform-class-properties', 
               'transform-object-rest-spread', 
               'transform-es2015-modules-amd']
    presets: [ 'react','es2015']
  dist: 
    files: [{
      expand: true
      cwd: "src/foo/jsx"
      src: "**/*.js"
      dest: "build/foo/js/"
      ext: ".js"
      }]
```

The result works and generates the AMD modules as follows for instance for myreact.js module:

```
define(["exports", "react", "prop-types"], function (exports, _react, _propTypes) {
  "use strict";
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });
  var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);
  var _propTypes2 = _interopRequireDefault(_propTypes);
  function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
      default: obj
    };
  }
  var REQUIRED_FIELD_SYMBOL = "*";
  function Blah(props) {
    ...
  }
  exports.default = Blah;
});
```

Now, when I use this AMD module in my other AMD modules with define, it is undefined

```
define([..., 'foo/js/myreact'], function(..., RM) {

RM.Blah <---- this is undefied
RM.default <---- still undefied
```

The generated code does not return the exports.

Also, I noticed in my require.js generated bundle.js, the react model shows up as follows:

```
define('foo/js/myreact',["exports", "react", "prop-types"], 
   function (exports, _react, _propTypes){
..
}
```

I am not really defining exports anywhere in my require.js config file so how I am supposed to setup exports?

Basically, how should I use my react AMD modules within other AMD modules?

Comment: You seem to be looking for `RM.default` - that's the name of the export, not `Blah`.

Comment: That is also undefined

Comment: What AMD loader are you using? What do you get when you debug and inspect `RM`?

Comment: I am using require.js. I get Object {__esModule: true} when I print RM in the console so it is picked up but there is nothing on it. just __esModule and __protor__

Comment: Hm, weird. Any circular dependencies that could lead to the property being undefined in the first run?

Comment: I checked the buddle.js and this is how the module is defined. define('foo/js/myreact',["exports", "react", "prop-types"], function (exports, _react, _propTypes). I don not have anything in my require.js config to define exports. is that ok?

Comment: as for dependencies, I am printing RM as the first line so nothing else would get a chance to set it if I got your question right

Comment: @iCode `exports` is a module provided by RequireJS automatically. It is used to allow support for the `exports.something = ...` style of exporting things. Without it, the only way to export from a module would be through returning a value from the callback given to `define`.

Comment: @Louis: Thanks for the explanation. Any clue why things are not working then?

Comment: @iCode No. What you show in the question looks fine to me. Maybe there's some detail I'm just not latching on or the problem is in code or configuration you have not shown.

Comment: @iCode did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue atm.